# nodejs driver for mongodb enter infinite loop to ensure Min Pool Size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, infinite-loop

I use the official mongodb nodejs sdk with code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
```

at the beginning, db read **works well**, however, after a while, **code enter an infinite loop to function ensureMinPoolSize** (see picture 1), is there anything wrong?

**more info:**

(1) my code is multi-thread (8 threads), every thread can read db,

(2) db pool setting as picture 2,

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What does "multi-thread" mean, specifically? Do you mean worker threads? Are you sharing the database connection between threads somehow? Are you sure that the MongoDB driver actually supports this?

Comment: this logic happens in background thread and it's expected

Comment: Recursive `setTimeout()` is a bit more controllable version of `setInterval()`, which is simpler to use but lacks flexibility. The code says it checks size of the connection pool no more than 10 times per second when idle, and around 100 times per second when opening a connection.

Comment: @AlexBlex 10ms after it wasn't able to create a new connection.

Comment: @robertklep, I might read it wrong but 10ms timeout is executed unconditionally regardless of result of connection attempt. Just out of curiosity, what am I missing?

Comment: @AlexBlex apologies, you're correct there :) But you're not accounting for the time that is spent in the `createConnection` call (the additional timeout is required to fill up the connection pool).

Comment: @robertklep, yep, that's why it's "no more" and "around" ;) With enough efforts one can block the loop forever =)

Comment: @dododo yes, happens in background thread, but this blocks the main thread, how to tackle it to confirm the valid business logic?

Comment: @robertklep & Alex Blex thanks for your reply, yes, multi threads means worker-threads lib, I don't share connection among multi threads, every thread has their own   connections pool, so is there any debug suggestion? thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexBlex many thanks, could you give me more info

Comment: idk node, but I doubt it does any blocking, this logic just creates reserved connections for future usage if previously created connections were already closed, no need for blocking

Comment: @dododo from my testing, it will block the main thread (not return result to main thread through message channel)

Comment: thanks @dododo you are right, this logic ensureMinPoolSize is by design, and it doesn't block the main thread. the root cause is main thread enters an infinite loop, no available time to tackle data through the message channel from child thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, thanks @dododo, this logic ensureMinPoolSize is running in the background thread and by design!

the root cause is main thread enters an infinite loop, no available time to tackle data through the message channel from child thread.